# how to separate a string based on specific requirements

Tags: r, regex

I have a variable, a, it contains characters like :

```
DEVICE PRF .75MG 0.5ML
DEVICE PRF 1.5MG 0.5MLX4
CAP 12-25MG 30
CAP DR 60MG 100UD 3270-33 (32%)
```

I would like to split them into three parts(or variables):

```
x               y               z
DEVICE PRF    .75MG            0.5ML
DEVICE PRF     1.5MG          0.5MLX4
CAP           12-25MG           30
CAP DR         60MG          100UD 3270-33 (32%)
```

The first part is the description, the second is the strength, and the third part is the volume. 
I think I can use gregexpr(), but not sure how to implement it. 
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are the spaces space characters or tabs?

Comment: You probably want to use a regular expression for this, but the specifics will depend on the rules that define the different groups. For example, this regex [`^([^.0-9]+) ([.0-9-]*MG) (.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/QUFS97/1) will split the data you provided, but it makes some assumptions that might not be accurate

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
library(stringr)
str_match(x, "(.*)[ ]{1,}(.*(MG|ML))[ ]{1,}(.*)")[, -c(1, 4)]
#      [,1]         [,2]      [,3]                 
# [1,] "DEVICE PRF" ".75MG"   "0.5ML"              
# [2,] "DEVICE PRF" "1.5MG"   "0.5MLX4"            
# [3,] "CAP"        "12-25MG" "30"                 
# [4,] "CAP DR"     "60MG"    "100UD 3270-33 (32%)"
```

Assuming that the second/middle part always ends with MG or ML and has no spaces.

The pattern `(.*)[ ]{1,}(.*(MG|ML))[ ]{1,}(.*)` could be read as: the first part to match containing anything + at least one space + the second part to match ending in MG or ML + at least one space + the third part to match containing anything.

Comment: It might end with "ML" instead of "MG".

Comment: @LiliaFeng, ok, took that into account in the update.

Answer (score 0):

Using the assumption that the middle part has no spaces and always starts with a `.` or digit, we can do this in base R like this:

```
a <- c("DEVICE PRF .75MG 0.5ML", "DEVICE PRF 1.5MG 0.5MLX4",
       "CAP 12-25MG 30", "CAP DR 60MG 100UD 3270-33 (32%)")

a_as_csv <- sub('([^.0-9]*) ([.0-9][^ ]+) (.*)', '\\1,\\2,\\3', a)

read.csv(textConnection(a_as_csv), col.names = c('x', 'y', 'z'), header = F)
#            x       y                   z
# 1 DEVICE PRF   .75MG               0.5ML
# 2 DEVICE PRF   1.5MG             0.5MLX4
# 3        CAP 12-25MG                  30
# 4     CAP DR    60MG 100UD 3270-33 (32%)
```